# Element-wise 'and' for lists in python?

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
X = [True,False]
Y = [True,True]
```

I am trying to compare X[0] with Y[0] and X[1] with Y[1].

I tried

```
in [7]: X and Y
Out[7]: [True, True]
```

but the result I was expecting was [True,False].

What should I be doing?

Comment: If you have `numpy` installed you can use [`numpy.logical_and()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html#numpy.logical_and)

Comment: `X and Y` means if the first item is truthy (which a non-empty list is), evaluate to the value of the second item.

Answer (score 16):

This is a perfect opportunity to use `map`, because `and` can be represented with a built-in function:

```
import operator
X = [True,False]
Y = [True,True]
map(operator.and_, X,Y)
#=> [True, False]
```

The reason why you get the behaviour you did is that `and` performs operations on the operands as if they had `bool` applied to them. All non-empty lists evaluate to `True` in a boolean context.

As to the "list comprehension is always better" point: no it's not. The equivalent list comprehension is:

```
[x and y for x, y in zip(X, Y)]
```

Which has to build an intermediate object (either list or generator, depending on the python version), and still requires the reader to know what `zip` does, just as much as `map` does. It's also likely to be slightly slower (because map + builtin function is fast - it all happens in the C layer, essentially). In fact, `timeit` shows that `izip` is faster (see below), but I really think the readability point is more important; you may also see different results if performance really matters.

```
>>> timeit.timeit('map(operator.and_, X,Y)', 'import operator; import itertools; import random; X = [random.choice([True,False]) for _ in range(1000)]; Y = [random.choice([True,False]) for _ in range(1000)]', number=10000)
1.0160579681396484
>>> timeit.timeit('[x and y for x, y in zip(X, Y)]', 'import operator; import itertools; import random; X = [random.choice([True,False]) for _ in range(1000)]; Y = [random.choice([True,False]) for _ in range(1000)]', number=10000)
1.3570780754089355
>>> timeit.timeit('[x and y for x, y in itertools.izip(X, Y)]', 'import operator; import itertools; import random; X = [random.choice([True,False]) for _ in range(1000)]; Y = [random.choice([True,False]) for _ in range(1000)]', number=10000)
0.965054988861084
```

That said, if you need arbitrary numbers of lists, you need to use `all` in a list comprehension (or combined with `izip` directly); and `and_` is technically bitwise and, so be aware that might have funky results if working with numeric types other than `bool`.

Here is an `all` version:

```
import itertools
map(all,itertools.izip(X,Y,Z))
```

Comment: well list comprehension it's a lot better than map

Comment: @Ant In what way? It's unlikely to be faster (because map is fastest with builtin functions), and it's unlikely to be clearer.

Comment: +1 for functional way, and it's shorter than list comprehension and it's not building new list with `zip` (although it's possible to use `izip`)

Comment: @Marcin my bad it does. I thought OP asked why was (s)he getting that result

Comment: map should be avoided in cases like this simply because list comprehension is easier to read. Functional way may be really great but i would not reccomend it in this kinds of situation (it's python!). http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Comment: @Ant I disagree that a list comprehension would be easier to read here, not least because you'll need some kind of zip anyway, so you'll be using the "functional way", only less efficiently.

Comment: I don't know what's with the sudden trend in "must be a list-comp" over a builtin.... but this is how I'd do it... The only difference is that instead of truncating one sequence, it'll pad with `None` so you'll end up with padded `False` values - so functionally they're different

Comment: +1 - Hi, %timeit shows comprehension is twice faster than your method. Is it right? if so, why is it?

Comment: @Marcin and Jon - to quote Guido in PEP 279 - "filter and map should die and be subsumed into list comprehensions" - I believe they're trying to remove these functional constructs from future python versions.

Comment: @Ben Just because Guido says something, that doesn't mean it's gospel. He's backed down from removing functional constructs, and indeed you'll see that itertools has grown in version 3.

Comment: @AbidRahmanK I'd expect my version to be faster, because it all happens on the C level. Could you paste your code + results up somewhere?

Comment: yeah.. me too expected the same.. I will give the link soon

Comment: @Marcin I agree Guido's word isn't gospel, but I do think he has a pretty good grasp on what should and shouldn't be part of Python. The Zen of Python also says "there should be one (and only one) obvious way to do something", and I think list comprehensions are more obvious and readable. However, map and filter have their place.

Comment: @Marcin: Oops sorry... I mistook it.. actually me too got map as faster. But I read it in the reverse order... my bad..

Comment: @AbidRahmanK I've tried map vs comprehension with `itertools.izip` and comprehension performs a bit better in my tests

Comment: @RomanPekar: for me,``izip`` is better that ``zip``, but not to ``map``.

Comment: `operator.and_` is a bitwise `and` vs `x and y` is a boolean `and`. While this works for Python's `True` and `False` is may be a different result with different values in the two lists.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This problem has had me banging my head against a wall for an hour!  I'm not too keen on the list comprehension as it doesn't look very readable.

Comment: @Marcin actually brain burp - don't think you can do `map(all...` *cough*

Comment: @Ben (1) Guido did eventually change his position (2) he obviously has a problem with functional programming (3) he recognises that the community in general should judge what should be in python, because he is pragmatic (4) in python there is usually more than one way to do it: that line was a rebuke to the perl community, and not in fact a goal which has been pursued.

Comment: @user847663 You're very welcome. If you want to work with vectorised operations, check out `numpy`.

Comment: @user847663 You may wish to mark one of these answers as accepted. Obviously, I'd like it to be mine, but choose whichever you think is most helpful and "best" according to your judgment.

Answer (score 9):

All non-empty lists evaluate to `True` in a boolean context, and `and` evaluates to the last expression it evaluated (`Y` in this case), which is why you get the result you do. You want something like this:

```
[x and y for x, y in zip(X, Y)]
```

Comment: it could be even better if you use itertools.izip

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have and arbitrary group of lists:

```
A=[True, False, False]
B=[True, True, False]
C=[3,0,0]
```

Now write something that looks a bit like [itertools.izip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) but allows a function to be added:

```
def elements(*iterables, **kwds):
    func=kwds.get('func', None)
    iterables=map(iter, iterables)
    while iterables:
        t=tuple(map(next, iterables)) 
        if func is not None:
            yield func(t)
        else:
            yield t
```

Now add functions that will return the logical result of `F(A[0],B[0],C[0]...)`. For example, these each do the function described:

```
def ands(elements):
    ''' logical 'and' for all the elements'''
    return all(elements)

def ors(elements):
    ''' logical 'or' for all the elements'''
    return any(elements)

def bitand(elements):
    ''' bitwise 'and' for all the elements'''
    return reduce(operator.and_,elements)
```

Then just call the function:

```
print list(elements(A,B,C,func=ands))  
# [True, False, False]
```

Or for you specific example:

```
print list(elements([True,False],[True,True],func=ands))  
# [True, False]
```

Or just use `all` directly:

```
print list(elements([True,False],[True,True],func=all))   
# [True, False]
```

Comment: Something that "that looks a bit like `itertools.izip` but allows a function to be added" is `itertools.imap`.

Comment: `ands` is just equivalent to `all` - your code just passes a generator which recapitulates the underlying sequences. Likewise with `ors` and `any`.

Comment: @Marcin: Fair point. I did have that at the end but did not in the function. Thanks!

Comment: @Marcin: `Something that "that looks a bit like itertools.izip but allows a function to be added" is itertools.imap` Not quite true. You would need to do `list(itertools.imap(all,itertools.izip(X,Y))` to get the same thing.

Comment: Apart from `izip` not returning a list, your version just changes how the arbitrary number of arguments is passed to the mapping parameter function. You could equally well do `itertools.imap(lambda *p: all(p) ,A,B)`. Either way, it's a hell of a lot less code than writing your own slightly different `imap`.

Comment: @Marcin: `itertools.imap(lambda *p: all(p) ,A,B)` is ugly and hard to follow -- for me anyway. YMMV.